# Angular is working, but $scope not showing up

Tags: angularjs

I'm walking through a tutorial on Angular. I've tried following their Dev Guide and searching SO, I'm a little confused with all the versions of Angular.

I have a small app, a to-do app, and I can't get the $scope from my HomeCtrl to appear when the app loads the home template. When I load the home template, it's showing everything except the scope calls in the curly brackets {{ }}.

Here's what I have for my HomeCtrl.js:

```
 blocitoff.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function HomCtrl ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {                          
    alert("hello");
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
    $scope.hello = "no way bill it worked!";                                
}]);
```

Here's what I have for my home.html:

```
<body ng-controller="HomeCtrl"> 
<div> 
    <h2> hello there </h2>
    <h3> {{2+5}} </h3>
      I can add: {{ 1 + 2 }}.

    <p> {{$scope.hello}}</p>
    <p> {{ hello }} </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you for any help or tips.

Comment: Do you get any error(s) appear in the developer console? if the information inside the curly brackets isn't showing it sounds like the interpolation is failing...

Comment: You'll need to look at the index.html as explained in tutorial and rest files such as app.js controller.js alone would not help

Comment: Be aware that your injected arguments: '$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject' and in a different order than your actual arguments: $scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray. Also you don't use the word `$scope` within your template. Instead of {{$scope.hello}} just use {{hello}}

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `$scope` identifier in the view (the HTML). `$scope` is only accessible within the JavaScript.

The whole point of `$scope` is that expressions in the view will, by default, refer to values on the scope. So if you want to access `$scope.hello`, refer to it as `hello`, as you are already doing:

```
<p> {{ hello }} </p>
```

Working example:

```js
var blocitoff = angular.module('blocitoff', []);

blocitoff.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function HomCtrl ($scope) {                          
    $scope.hello = "no way bill it worked!";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="blocitoff" ng-controller="HomeCtrl"> 
<div> 
    <h2> hello there </h2>
    <h3> {{2+5}} </h3>
      I can add: {{ 1 + 2 }}.

    <p> {{ hello }} </p>
</div>
</body>
```